# Use regular expression to extract numbers before specific words

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

**Goal**

Extract number before word `hours`, `hour`, `day`, or `days`

1. How to use `|` to match the words?

```
s = '2 Approximately 5.1 hours 100 ays 1 s'
re.findall(r"([\d.+-/]+)\s*[days|hours]", s) # note I do not know whether string s contains hours or days
```

return

```
['5.1', '100', '1']
```

Since 100 and 1 are not before the exact word hours, they should not show up. Expected

```
5.1
```

2. How to extract the first number from the matched result

```py
s1 = '2 Approximately 10.2 +/- 30hours'
re.findall(r"([\d. +-/]+)\s*hours|\s*hours", s)
```

return

```py
['10.2 +/- 30']
```

Expect

```
10.2
```

Note that special characters  `+/-.` is optional. When `.` appears such as `1.3`, 1.3 will need to show up with the `.`. But when `1 +/- 0.5` happens, 1 will need to be extracted and none of the `+/-` should be extracted.

I know I could probably do a split and then take the first number

```
str(re.findall(r"([\d. +-/]+)\s*hours", s1)[0]).split(" ")[1]
```

Gives

```
'10.2'
```

But some of the results only return one number so a split will cause an error. Should I do this with another step or could this be done in one step?

Please note that these strings `s1`, `s2` are the values in a dataframe. Therefore, iteration using function like `apply` and `lambda` will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
import re
units = '|'.join(["hours", "hour", "hrs", "days", "day", "minutes", "minute", "min"])  # possible units
number = '\d+[.,]?\d*'                              # pattern for number
plus_minus = '\+\/\-'                               # plus minus

cases = fr'({number})(?:[\s\d\-\+\/]*)(?:{units})'

pattern = re.compile(cases)
```

**Tests**

```
print(pattern.findall('2 Approximately 5.1 hours 100 ays 1 s'))   
# Output: [5.1]

print(pattern.findall('2 Approximately 10.2 +/- 30hours'))        
# Output: ['10.2']

print(pattern.findall('The mean half-life for Cetuximab is 114 hours (range 75-188 hours).'))        
# Output: ['114', '75']

print(pattern.findall('102 +/- 30 hours in individuals with rheumatoid arthritis and 68 hours in healthy adults.'))        
# Output: ['102', '68']

print(pattern.findall("102 +/- 30 hrs"))                          
# Output: ['102']

print(pattern.findall("102-130 hrs"))                             
# Output: ['102']

print(pattern.findall("102hrs"))                                  
# Output: ['102']

print(pattern.findall("102 hours"))                               
# Output: ['102']
```

**Explanation**

Above uses the convenience that raw strings (r'...') and string interpolation f'...' can be combined to:

```
fr'...'
```

per [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#raw-f-strings)

The cases strings:

```
fr'({number})(?:[\s\d\-\+\/]*)(?:{units})'
```

Parts are sequence:

- fr'({number})' - capturing group '(\d+[.,]?\d*)' for integers or floats
- r'(?:[\s\d-+/]*)' - non capturing group for allowable characters between number and units (i.e. space, +, -, digit, /)
- fr'(?:{units})' - non-capturing group for units

Comment: Would you mind explaining what does `fr''` do and what does `?:` do in the code `cases = fr'({number})(?:{case1}|{case2})'`? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @June--added a note with a reference to raw f-strings (i.e. raw interpolated strings).  String interpolation is simple: x = 5; s = f'{x}' creates a string s = '5' (i.e. string interpolation allows for variable substitution in strings).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have found another question regarding the code. If we have a string `s = 'The mean half-life for Cetuximab is 114 hours (range 75-188 hours).'` Then execute `pattern.findall(str(s))` will give result `[' 114', '75-188']`. This looks weird to me because it seems like `cases` should only take the first unit value since it is a `"|"`. Am I not understanding it correctly? Is there a way to get rid of the space before the number and only take `114` as the result.

Comment: @June--made an update that should provide a better result.

Comment: @June--added a fix for '102 +/- 30 hours in individuals with rheumatoid arthritis and 68 hours in healthy adults.'.  It results in ['102', '68'].  Are having both these numbers the desired result in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224503/discussion-between-darrylg-and-june).

Comment: When `s = '70-80 min'`, `print(pattern.findall(s))` will give `['80']` instead of `['70']`. If I change the code to `units = '|'.join(["min", "minutes", "minute"])`                       `plus_minus = '\-'`
`cases = fr'({number})\s*(?:{plus_minus}\s*{number})*?\s*(?:{units}*?)'`. This will give the right result `['70']`. But I do need a combination of `+ - /` and `plus_minus = '|'.join(["\+","\-", "\/"])` does not work. Any comment?

Comment: How would you handle an apostrophe at the end of one of your possible units - such as something like " years' "? Your solution works great - I can't seem to get it to work for a possible unit that includes years' - it's just omitted.

Comment: @Hatt - IIUC:  adding year` with - `units = '|'.join(["years'", "hours", "hour", "hrs", "days", "day", "minutes", "minute", "min"])`.  Then `print(pattern.findall("2 Approximately 5.1 years' 100 ays 1 s"))` returns ['5.1'] as desired.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
units = ["hours", "hour", "days", "day"]   # the order matters here: put plurals first
regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(units) + r')'
s = '2 Approximately 5.1 hours 100 ays 1 s'
values = re.findall(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+' + regex, s)
print(values)  # prints [('5.1')]
```

If you want to *also* capture the units being used, then make the units alternation *capturing*, i.e. use:

```
regex = r'(' + '|'.join(units) + r')'
```

Then the output would be:

```
[('5.1', 'hours')]
```

Comment: in case , s = '2 Approximately 5.1hours 100 ays 1 s' - no space before hours. This does not work. How to have it work when there is no space before hours